# Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes in google directory API when logging through admin

Tags: reactjs, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm using google admin directory API to get all accounts public information using following API 
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

here is link for this api [link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users)
when I logged in using **g suite** domain account let say abc@somedomain.com with non **administrative user** this api works fine and fetch the data of all accounts in array
 but When I call this API by logging in as admin it gives me following error /

---

> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication
>   scopes

---

why its happening Im using same auth and API key for both users
my code is here

```
const token =localStorage.getItem('token')
 fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users? 
 domain=${domain.url}&viewType=domain_public&key=${apiKey.key}`  
  ,{ headers: {
'authorization': 'Bearer '+token
  },})

  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ users:data.users }));
```

token is coming from this module [npm react google login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) google sign in button

Comment: Hello @Asad, what scopes did you use for the request? Moreover, did you use any parameters for the request?

Comment: Scope is set by default like first im logining  with google auth then im sending two params `view_type` and `domain` here you can look https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list @ale13

Comment: im sending my domain name domain.com and `view_type` = domain_public for non admin user

Comment: with access token in header like this `bearer xxxxx` xxx is access token @ale13

Comment: Hello @Asad, how are you calling the API? What are you getting if you are using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) with the same parameters as above? Cheers!

Comment: Im first logging in through google sign in button , In response I'm getting access token and then Im sending this access token in header to call api with above 2 parameters @ale13

Comment: Im calling api with simple `fetch` method in reactjs

Comment: Hey @Asad, have you tried the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? What results are you getting? Cheers!

Comment: iits working there :/ i have added scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` but when i add this scope to admin account it dont work while works for non admin user @ale13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the issue you are encountering is related to the way you are using the access token, more precisely in the way you use the scopes for the **admin account** in relation to the `access token` you have.

If the scopes you want to use with the two accounts don't match entirely, **you will need to get another access token** when you use the admin account.

So in order to solve your issue, you will have to get a new access token for the scopes you will be using for the **admin account**. You can declare them like this:

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly' 'OTHER_SCOPE_1' 'OTHER_SCOPE_2'...];
```

Same goes for the **non-admin account**; if the scopes don't match entirely, declare them like above and get another `access token` which will be the one matching them.

**Reference**

- [Authorizing Requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

Comment: uh yes It was issue of scope and i was stuck in how to add in that react module,  but I learnt it well still wondering how it works for `non admin user`  thank you so much for your time :)  @ale13

Comment: @Asad you’re welcome and I’m glad to hear everything works as expected now :)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @ale13 I came to know that I need to add scopo in `react-module` [react google login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)

so I added following scope

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

and I still don't know how this works for non admin user without adding scope

Answer (score 0):

Reason:
During the instance creation in "Access scopes" you used the Default option need to choose the "Allow full access to all Cloud APis" option.

Once you already created do the steps:

*) stop the VM instance
*) click in Edit , next in API access scopes select "Allow full access to all Cloud APis" and click in save
*) Start instance and check please